# How to get and set a list class property?

Tags: c#, .net

I do you set and get a list of type class program property in Main ? if I do  I get an Exception?

```
public class Person 
{
    public List<Person> Children { get; set; }
    public string Names { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    var person = new Person 
    {
        Names = "King"
    };
    
    person.Children.Add(new Person()); // Null Reference Exception
}
```

Comment: You can't use `Children` when it is null. Create an instance of it first like in the answer below that does not give you an explanation of why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
   var person = new Person{Names= "King" , Children=new List<Person>()};
   person.Children.Add(new Person())
```